# Simple CSS HTML layout issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble writing a CSS layout with centered content, simple image header, two columns (nav and main content) and finally a footer below that.

The problem is that I can't get the nav/main content columns to hold a size (200 and 718px respectively) and stay centered with the header/footer as the browser window is manipulated.

I've tried various types of positioning and containers, floating the nav/main columns always breaks them out of the container.

Any ideas?

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  max-width: 918px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: #111 solid 2px;
}

.main {
  display: inline;
  width: 700px;
}

.footer {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;  
}
```

html:

```
<body>
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">navigation</div>
            <div class="main">main</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you want main div below nav or in the right side of nav??

Comment: I needed main div to the right of the nav....slash197 had the perfect solution!  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.nav { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }
.main { display: inline-block; width: 700px; }
.container { display: block; width: 900px; margin: 0px auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you css with this on

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px; 
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  max-width: 918px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border:1px solid red;
}

.container {
clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.contain{

width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
.nav {
  width: 200px;
  border-right: #111 solid 2px;
   border:1px solid yellow;
    float:left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.main {
  width: 718px;
   border:1px solid blue;
   float:left;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}

.footer {
clear:both;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;  
           border:1px solid green;
}
```

and HTMl with this one .

```
<body>
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contain">
                <div class="nav">navigationnavigationnavigationnavigationnavigationnavitionnavigation</div>
                <div class="main">mainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmnmainmainmainmain</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

This will work fine then.

Best of luck....